# Embed C# or PHP code in Cognos

Tags: c#, php, cognos

Sorry for this newbie type question. I am not a Cognos developer.

Is there a way to embed C# or PHP code in Cognos? I tried putting some PHP code in a HTML block but that didn't work. Our Cognos installation is on IIS 7.

Comment: Does the server have PHP installed on it as well as Cognos? Where in Cognos are you wanting to run PHP/C# scripts? Question is currently too vague.

Comment: @FDL I agree with the vagueness part (sorry)... I am trying to put the PHP code in the body of a report. The server has PHP installed and also Cognos 10.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what are you trying to achieve with PHP or C#? People usually use Javascript in reports, but if you want to use other languages like PHP, you can try out Cognos Mashup Services.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1001cognosmashup/

Be aware, you need to have an SDK license to use it (at least needed the last time I check). Maybe worth running this through IBM rep.

Comment: I did not know you can set cookies with JavaScript. Thanks again.